# Printing sIFR in IE7

Tags: printing, sifr3, css

I'm using sIFR3 to render some text on a website. That site has print feature that will replace the page frame and leave only the text. An appropriate sIFR-alternate style for printing is set as well.

The problem I'm running into is that sIFR puts a CSS min-height as an inline style on the H2 that is replaced. And due to this setting, that seems to be calculated from the font-size given for that element, IE7 cuts off letters like gpq - letters that go below the baseline of the text.

I have tried and googled for a solution but couldn't find anything relating to this issue. Or how I could stop sIFR from setting the min-height value altogether.

You can test with any sIFR Text that falls back to Arial, for example, with a given height on the element it is located in (even non-pixel values).

Thanks and cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at a few projects i implemented with sIFR and i could not reproduce the error you described.

A few suggestions that maybe help:

1. You could try to work with padding
   and margin instead of giving a
   height value if that's possible.
2. Try to define line-height for the sIFR containing element. In both screen and print stylesheets.
3. Overwrite the min-height value inside the print stylesheet: `selector{min-height:value !important;}`

Are you sure that it is because of the min-height-style that the descender is cutted? Did you try to remove the style using e.g. Firebug?